WordPress and Google maps perimeter calculation integration
I'm creating a website using WordPress.
I need a function on the page where a customer can enter an address, mark their property with boundary points, and calculate the perimeter length (m). Based on this, an approximate estimated cost of work will be calculated.
Google Maps has a perimeter calculation function.
I want to create something similar to what is used on the Husqvarna website (lawn calculator):
https://automower.husqvarna.com/us/index.html
Thanks in advance
I tried to find plugin with similar functionality but unsuccessfully.
